# Effect of decreasing phase and magnitude of Fourier transform in image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

What is the Effect of decreasing phase and magnitude of the Fourier transform of an image?  How can that be done with matlab?  I have an image `A`, I  want to set the phase of image `A`'s Fourier transform zero then make the magnitude of the image `A`'s transform zero and see the effect on the image.

What should I do?

```matlab
A=imread('sample.tif');
F=fft2(A);
F2=fftshift(F);
F_inverse=ifft2(F);
subplot(2,2,1);imshow(A);
title('Original Image');
subplot(2,2,2);imshow(log(1+abs(F2)),[]);
title('Fourier Spectrum');
subplot(2,2,3);imshow(angle(F2),[-pi pi]);
title('Fourier Phase');
subplot(2,2,4);imshow(F_inverse,[]);
title('Inverse Fourier');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
f1 = real(F);
f2 = imag(F);
magnitude = abs(F);
Fnew=real(ifft2(f0)); % set all phases to zero
figure,imagesc(Fnew)
```

The pixels are all zero if you set all the magnitude zero. You can set two parameters `a` and `b` by yourself, and observe the change of `real(ifft2(a*f1 + i*b*f2))` with `imagesc`

Comment: Thanks,In the digital image,phase is important or magnitude?

Comment: I would say both. And depend how and what regions you are tuning. Basically the phase brings you different contrasts even in the same object in an image. And magnitude on some specific frequencies represented in the shape or edges in the image.